# Finding the filename and file path of a function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, traceback

I have large number of python files where classes are also inheriting and overriding methods. I am tracking calls of the functions. Is there a way I can get the details of the function (where it is located in which file) without the actual call of the function (for example, just by passing object and function name)?

Not to forget that objects are dynamic. So just listing all function names of the project isn't useful.

File 1:

```
class ABC(DEF):
    def Start(self):
        pass
```

File 2:

```
class XYZ(DEF):
    def Start(self):
        pass
```

.

.

.

File n:

```
class PQR(AQZ):
    def Activity(self):
        obj = ABC()
        # How to know in which file, the function Start is defined
        obj.Start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [the `inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html). It's not always going to work (builtins implemented in C won't necessarily have line numbers, or even associated files, since some modules like `sys` are baked into the core interpreter, not distributed as separate files), but it's the closest you're going to get to what you're looking for.

Updating your example to provide info on the origin of things:

```
import inspect

class PQR(AQZ):
     def Activity(self):
        obj = ABC()
        # How to know in which file, the function Start is defined
        try:
            _, lineno = inspect.getsourcelines(obj.Start)
            srcfile = inspect.getsourcefile(obj.Start)
        except TypeError:
            print("{!r} is a built-in".format(obj.Start))
        else:
            print("{!r} comes from {!r}, line {}".format(obj.Start, srcfile, lineno))
        obj.Start()
```

Comment: I don't worry about C. I need python file related information only. Will it be possible for you to elaborate more with an example.

Comment: @AnshumanGoel: Well, in general, I don't bother with it directly; I'm introspecting in `ipython`, where the `??` operator does this for you (e.g. `collections.Counter??` displays the source code for `collections.Counter`). All it's doing is wrapping use of [the various source code retrieval functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code). I'm not sure of your exact use case (you wouldn't pass it object and function name, just a bound method of the object, though `getattr` would allow you to convert from the former to the latter).

Comment: I suspect `inspect.getsourcelines` is what you need (returns a `list` of `str` lines, and the starting line number), as well as `inspect.getfile` to get the file it originated in, but your use case is rather vague to provide a more useful example.

Comment: I have added one small example in the question. Probably it can help.

Comment: @AnshumanGoel: I've added a brief example. Mind you, your example use case isn't all that interesting (you *know* you made and `ABC`, because you made it on the prior line). The interesting case is where you receive an object as an argument without knowing where it came from/what it is (so you don't know if it's an `ABC`, `XYZ`, or something else); `inspect` can (often) suss it out.